# Get all uploaded files of today in a directory php

Tags: php, directory

I'm trying to get the amount of all uploaded files of today in a directory with php. The directory is called 's', and all files in it are jpg and/or png files.

Thank you.

Comment: Given that just barely qualifies as PHP, I'd suggested by RTFMing first: http://php.net/date http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
$dir = 's';
$i = 0;
//here list of files of your directory with extension (jpg, jpeg, png) case insenstive
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}', GLOB_BRACE);
    $currentDate = date("F d Y");
    if (!empty($files) && is_array($files)) {
        foreach ($files as $f) {
            if (date("F d Y", filemtime($f)) == $currentDate) {
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
return $i;
```

Comment: I'm glad that it worked ! Thanks !
You can validate my answer as best answer if it did the trick
Thanks !